# Node App is running in server but not working when trying in browser

Tags: node.js

I have small node app that is doing some operations with the database, it is working fine locally but when i try to run it in the cloud server it is showing as running but unable to see anything on browser

I am using express framework and the server is running in centOS. 
I tried many solutions but nothing is working

```
// app.js
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
var cors = require('cors');
const http = require('http');

const routes1 = require('./routes/routes');

// initialize our express app
const app = express();

// const mongoDB = process.env.MONGODB_URI || dev_db_url;
mongoose.connect('<My mlab details>');
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
const db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'MongoDB connection error:'));

var publicDir = require('path').join(__dirname,'/uploads/images/products');
app.use(express.static(publicDir));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(cors())


app.use('/api/routes', routes1);


let port = 80;

const server = http.createServer(app);

server.listen(port)

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('Server is up and running on port numner ' + port);
});
```

I am expecting the port to listen properly and store in the mlab server

Comment: don't use port 80. use port > 1024. Also two instance is trying to bind to same port.

Comment: "the cloud server" can be any of a large number of possible configurations.  Information about your deployment target is required to know how to help you fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from your code it looks like you are using express

here you are initialling express

```
 const app = express();
```

just attach listner to app


remove this two line of code

```
const server = http.createServer(app);

server.listen(port)
```

and use port like this

```
let port = process.env.PORT || 8000;
```

it will solve your problem

this is working code

```
// app.js
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
var cors = require('cors');
const http = require('http');

const routes1 = require('./routes/routes');

// initialize our express app
const app = express();

// const mongoDB = process.env.MONGODB_URI || dev_db_url;
mongoose.connect('<My mlab details>');
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
const db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'MongoDB connection 
error:')); 

var publicDir = 
  require('path').join(__dirname,'/uploads/images/products');
  app.use(express.static(publicDir));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(cors())


app.use('/api/routes', routes1);

let port = process.env.PORT || 8000;



app.listen(port, () => {
console.log('Server is up and running on port numner ' + port);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment my issue was with the cloud server. The IP was block due to some problem. Anyways your answer helped me .. :)